# ERD--> sql transformation

Tags: sql, database-design, erd

I am having issues with translating my ER diagram into tables. In a ternary relationship with weak entities, according to the requirements:

- A supplier supplies certain number parts for a project
- A project uses the parts from the different suppliers.
- The same kind partsfrom different suppliers are used by different
  projects.
- There is a name for a supplier and the city where the supplier
  locates.
- There is a name, color, and weight for a part.

[image: ERD Diagram Image]

Do I create a fourth table for supplies containing: projectNO, supplierName, City, Partname, color and weight? 6 attributes that makes up the PK for that table?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your relationship between `Project` and `Supplies` is right.  Similarly, your relationships between `Supplies` and each of `Supplier` and `Part` are all backwards.

The crow's foot goes at the many end of the relationship.  `Supplies` should be the ternary relationship table that you're talking about.  If you are using natural keys then all of the key columns from `Project`, `Supplier` and `Part` should appear in `Supplies` as both FK to their respective tables and all together as PK.

However, your natural keys look like things that could change (e.g. supplier moves cities, part changes colour or weight).  I think you might want to consider using surrogate keys to avoid future update anomalies.

Comment: supplies table(projNO,suppName,city,partName,color,weight) all the
attributes of this table make up the PK !

ok how about a supplier ID, and a part ID? as surrogate keys
that would make it simpler:
Project(projNO{PK},...)
Supplier(ID{PK},name,city)
part(ID{PK},name,color,weight)
project_supply_part(projNO,SuppID,PartID) and all att's make up the primiary key

Comment: @Programmingbuddy - Yes, that is the general idea.  The surrogate keys keep the intersection table tidy and allow you to edit some of your parent table columns without disturbing your foreign keys.